# How do I reset a textbox and make the value in the textbox equal to "" (or blank)? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, passwords

I wrote several functions to check if the two passwords are equal. I first type two passwords. When I click out of the "verify password" box, it should either display "The passwords match" or "A second try is needed. Please enter your password in the first password box again because the two passwords don't match" depending on whether or not the passwords are equal to each other. If the two passwords are not equal, the message "A second try is needed. Please enter your password in the first password box again because the two passwords don't match" is displayed. I also want the first password box (password1) to turn blank (I want it reset) as well when the two passwords do not match. However, that won't work in my code. What I am doing wrong here?

I used a password.js file and a setpassword.html file.

My password.js file is this:

```
var verifypasswordclick = document.getElementById("txtPWVerified");

function verifypassword1() {
    var password1 = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
    var verifypassword = document.getElementById("txtPWVerified").value;
    if(password1 == '' || verifypassword == '') {
        return null;
    }
    if(password1 == verifypassword) {
        alert('The passwords match');
    }
    if(password1 !== verifypassword || password1 == "" || verifypasword == "") {
        alert("A second try is needed. Please enter your password in the first password box again because the two passwords don't match");
    }
    if(password1 !== verifypassword || password1 == "" || verifypasword == "") {
        password1 = "";
    }
}
verifypasswordclick.addEventListener("blur",verifypassword1);
```

My setpassword.html file is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- H5FormValidation.html -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Register Here</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Register Here</h2>

  <form id="formTest" method="get" action="processData">
    <table>

    <tr>
      <td><label for="txtEmail">Email<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="email" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="txtPassword">Password<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="password" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="txtPWVerified">Verify Password<span class="required">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" id="txtPWVerified" name="pwVerified" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
          <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" id="btnReset"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
 <script src = "password.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("txtPassword").value = '';`

Comment: Thanks! Your code works, but I am wondering why you need to grab that value again if I already defined password1 as that.

Comment: @MichaelBao Strings are pass by value in JavaScript, so if you make a reference to a string and modify it, it will not modify the original string.  When you stored `password1`, you made a copy of that value.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the value of the password element (thanks to the id of the element)

```
document.getElementById("txtPassword").value = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you password.js  code as follow.

```
var verifypasswordclick = document.getElementById("txtPWVerified");
function verifypassword1() {
        var password1 = document.getElementById("txtPassword")
        var verifypassword = document.getElementById("txtPWVerified");
        //do nothing until the fields is field
        if(password1.value && verifypassword.value){
            if(password1.value === verifypassword.value) {
                alert('The passwords match');
            }else{
                alert("A second try is needed. Please enter your password in the first password box again because the two passwords don't match");
                password1.value= "";
    
            }
        }
    }
verifypasswordclick.addEventListener("blur",verifypassword1);
```